# Search for duplicate records without knowing which column is having duplicate values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, oracle12c

I have a table which has 30 columns and I want to find out the duplicates in this table but I don't know which column is having duplicates.

That's why I don't want to use :

```
select column_name, count(column_name)
from table
group by column_name
having count (column_name) > 1;
```

as this would require I have to repeat for all 30 columns.

Is there any way to do it in one single query?

Comment: Seems strange... Why do you want to do that?

Comment: because it is being used to populate another table which is having Primary key constraint so it is giving error while trying to insert duplicate records

Comment: Add that populate another table query. And both tables' definitions.

Comment: Then you don't need to check that for **every** column, only the columns you use to populate that other table's primary key.

Comment: the problem is I am inserting all 30 columns

Comment: Yeah but check which of the 30 columns is matching with the one with Primary Key constraint in the second table.

Comment: How many columns does the PK of the _target_ table have? Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the target table (including the PK definition and all indexes) **and** the `insert` statement you are using. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all combinations use [`group by cube`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#cube)

```
select column1, column2,..., column30,count(*)
from table
group by cube (column1, column2,..., column30)
having count (*) > 1;
```